# Normalizing a set of values based on the size of the set?

Tags: normalization

So I track my stats for League of Legends, which is an online battle arena game. I get to track stats like kills, deaths, assists, and kda (which is kills+assists/deaths). I love tracking the variance on these stats, because it helps me get a better indication of my long-term performance. While tracking these stats is great, I have this problem when some of the sample sizes are small.

There are different characters to use, and so I may have a set of 100 samples for character A, and a set of 4 samples for character B. My stats for character A obviously reflect a better picture because of the larger sample. In some cases, my stats for character B are better, but with a much smaller sample size, there's obviously some issues taking it at face value.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to normalize the values. Can I come up with a formula that factors in the smaller sample size? If there's not, is there instead a way to calculate confidence in the data? Surely, I can at least determine how reliable the values are given that the data set is much smaller.

If anything's not clear or you need some samples, let me know. Thanks.